# Busca e ordem dos elementos angularjs

Tags: javascript, classificação, algoritmo-de-busca

Se eu possuo um conjunto de dados contendo 50 elementos, desses 50 eu preciso que haja uma iteração para mostrar 10 em 10, os 10 primeiros e depois sucessivamente. Se dentro desse mesmo conjunto com 50 elementos eu precise pesquisar por algo que tenha nesse conjunto, quando apagado ele tem que retornar os 10 primeiros elementos.

Como faço isso com o angularjs?

A consulta funciona mas quando apago a palavra pesquisada ela retorna todos os elemntos do conjunto.

```js
scope.$watch('q', function(newValue, oldValue) {
 if (oldValue != null){
  $http.get('/api/services.json?q=' + newValue)
   .success(function (data) {
      $scope.services = data;
     });
  }
 }, true);
```

Comment: Sua pergunta está bem confusa. Sugiro que você dê um exemplo prático do que você quer fazer para que fique mais claro.

Comment: Possuo um conjunto com 50 elementos servidos em uma página web localmente, esses elementos estão paginados 10 a 10, a página em que são exibidos esses elementos possui uma busca, quando é executada a busca ele retorna perfeitamente o elemento no conjunto, caso ache, se apagar a pesquisa feita aí a página carrega todos os elementos para serem mostrados, ignora a paginação!

Comment: já tentou um filter direto no ng-repeat ?

Comment: A filtragem para retorno do elemento pesquisado está funcionando, o que é problema mesmo é que quando apaga a pesquisa feita ele retorna todos os elementos do conjunto e era para retornar somente os 10 primeiros.